# Remove duplicated rows in group with condition on values

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a pandas dataset (df) like below.
I would like to group records on columns ['col1','col3'] values and in each group drop records that have null value for 'col2' if there is a record with not null value for col2 in the group.
what can I do for that, many thanks in advance !

```
I have this df:
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   A   1    5   x
1   A   NA   5   y
2   A   NA   5   z
3   A   1    2   z
4   A   NA   2   z
5   B   NA   3   z
6   B   NA   4   z
```

I would like to have this:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0   A   1    5   x
3   A   1    2   z
5   B   NA   3   z
6   B   NA   4   z
```

(in this case records 1,2 should be dropped because record 0 has not null value for col2)
(in this case records 4 should be dropped because record 3 has not null value for col2)

Comment: If there are are multiple non-null `col2` values for a given `col1` and `col3` combination, should both be kept? E.g., if you added a row A, 2, 5, x to the dataset

Comment: `df.groupby(['col1', 'col3'], as_index=False).first()`?

Comment: to Robert Robison: yes the other non-null values for col2 have to be kept. so if there is a row A, 2, 5, x it should be kept too.

Comment: #Mozway : Very smart solution, but it won't work for situation in group with multiple non-null value for col2 (that all of them have to be kept)